# How to extract hour:minute from a datetime stamp in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, python-datetime

I have dataframe as given below: df=

```
                          POA                ...          Inverter efficiency
2019-01-25 08:00:00    20.608713         ...                      0.708626
2019-01-29 08:00:00   200.250137         ...                      0.017787
2019-01-29 08:30:00   347.699615         ...                      0.000000
2019-01-29 09:00:00   492.822662         ...                      0.000000
2019-01-29 09:30:00   620.336243         ...    
.
.                 
2019-03-07 13:00:00  1151.468384         ...                      1.067493
2019-03-07 13:30:00  1119.876831         ...                      2.311577
2019-03-07 14:00:00  1038.760864         ...                      3.395081
```

I want to plot 24 hours plot for all days. My code

```
plot(df.index.hour,df['POA'])
```

Result is:

[image: Hourly data of all days]

However, there is a data at 08:30, 09:30,..., etc. But it is not reflected in plot. In fact, these intermediary hour data points are combined with 08, 09hr, etc data. So, my question is, how to show 08.30, 09.30,...,etc data as well on plot? (Looks like I have to extract both hour and minute from same datetime)

My accepted below answer gives following plot and this is what I wanted. But, x-axis ticks are clubbed together. They don't appear as in my first above plot. How to correct x-axis ticks in my second plot?: '

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#rng = pd.date_range('1/5/2018 00:00', periods=5, freq='35T')
#df = pd.DataFrame({'POA':randint(1, 10, 5)}, index=rng)
labels = df.index.strftime('%H:%M')
x = np.arange(len(labels))
plt.plot(x, df['POA'])
plt.xticks(x, labels)
```

Steps:

- `labels = df.index.strftime('%H:%M')` => Convert the datetime to "Hours:minutes" format to use as x labels
- `x = np.arange(len(labels))` => Create a dummy x axis for matplotlib
- `plt.plot(x, df['POA'])` => Make the plot
- `plt.xticks(x, labels)` => Replace the x labels with datetime

Assumption: The datetime index is sorted, if not the graph will be messed up. If the index is not in sorted order then sort it before plotting for correct results.

We can further enhance the x axis to include seconds, dates, etc by using the appropriate string formatter in df.index.strftime

### Solution with skipping x-ticks to avoid clubbed x labels

```
#rng = pd.date_range('1/5/2018 00:00', periods=50, freq='35T')
#df = pd.DataFrame({'POA':randint(1, 10, 50)}, index=rng)
labels = df.index.strftime('%H:%M')
x = np.arange(len(labels))
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.plot(x, df['POA'])
plt.xticks(x, labels)
skip_every_n = 10
for i, x_label in enumerate(ax.xaxis.get_ticklabels()):
    if i % skip_every_n != 0:
        x_label.set_visible(False)
```

Comment: or simply, plt.plot(df.index.strftime('%H:%M'),df['POA'])

Comment: @AlexK, I am not sure it will work because plot needs floats(numbers) in axis and you are passing  strings in x-axis

Comment: It will work under that same assumption that the datetime index is already sorted (otherwise, you may see something like 11:00 preceding 08:00).  The x-axis is a Pandas series index in this case.

Comment: Great! it worked. But, x-axis ticks look clubbed. How to see few ticks and look neat? Please see my above edited question.

Comment: @Msquare How about plt.xticks(x, labels, rotation=90) which will rotate the labels ?

Comment: @mujjiga, No. There are many timestamps and it looks bad. So, I would want something like as in my first plot.